# Existe algum estrutura de hash em R?

Tags: r

Existe alguma estrutura de hash em R, semelhante ao dictionaries do Python e do javascript?

Isso facilita bastante a programação.

Comment: Se o seu objetivo for apenas a "ideia" de hashes, no sentido key/value, você pode simplesmente utilizar vetores com nome, por exemplo `setNames(1:10, letters[1:10])`, ou listas, para dados de classes diferentes ou mais complexos. A grande vantagem é trabalhar com estruturas básicas compatíveis com praticamente qualquer coisa em R. O pacote `hash` só vai ser útil se você precisar acessar um valor pela chave e o tamanho da hash for > 500 (segundo o próprio manual do pacote).

Comment: @Molx, muito bom comentário!  Era isso mesmo que eu queria. Você poderia colocar como resposta.

Comment: Environments também podem ser usados como hash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como explicado na resposta do próprio @GuilhermeDuarte, não existe uma estrutura essencialmente do tipo hash nativa do R, mas há um pacote que a implementa.

É importante ressaltar, no entanto, que esse pacote só tem utilidade caso seja necessário se aproveitar da grande vantagem de hashes, que é a possibilidade de se obter um valor a partir de uma chave com ótima performance. Ainda assim, o próprio [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/hash.pdf) informa que o pacote só supera as funções do *base* para hashes com mais de 500 elementos.

Se o objetivo é simplificar o código e organizar as variáveis por nomes, existem basicamente duas formas de se fazer isso em R utilizando as estruturas básicas, que tem como grande vantagem a compatibilidade direta com as outras funções nativas e pacotes de terceiros.

Para dados mais simples, como uma sequencia de elementos da mesma classe (número, string, fator), chamados vetores, em R, podemos utilizar vetores com nome. Por exemplo:

```
> vet <- 1:10
> vet
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

> names(vet) <- letters[1:10]
> vet
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Cada valor do vetor pode ser acessado pelo seu nome utilizando `[[ ]]`, por exemplo:

```
> vet[["d"]]
[2] 4
```

Para se criar o vetores já com os nomes em uma linha, pode se usar `setNames`:

```
> vet2 <- setNames(11:20, letters[11:20])
> vet2
 k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Para dados mais complexos, pode se usar listas. As listas tem várias propriedades elaboradas que fogem do escopo dessa resposta, mas em termos de nomes, podemos utilizar:

```
> lista <- list(elemento1 = vet, elemento2=vet2)
> lista
$elemento1
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  #Note que o nome dos elementos de vet foram mantidos, temos um vetor nomeado dentro de uma lista
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 

$elemento2
 k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Para acessar o elemento da lista pelo nome, podemos fazer como nos vetores:

```
> lista[["elemento1"]]
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Ou, utilizando um "atalho" que também deixa o código mais bonito:

```
> lista$elemento1
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Assim, ressalto que se o objetivo for unicamente a organização do código com uma estrutura do tipo chave/valor, as propriedades nativas do R fazem isso naturalmente. Detalhes sobre as razões que levam o pacote ter performance superior para mais de 500 elementos, assim como algumas informações sobre *Enviroments*, que também podem ser utilizados como hashes (como lembrando pelo @CarlosCinelli), podem ser encontrados nas respostas [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470447/can-i-use-a-list-as-a-hash-in-r-if-so-why-is-it-so-slow) do Stack Overflow em Inglês.

Answer (score 5):

Pode haver uma solução nativa, mas uma solução interessante é usar o pacote "hash".

POr exemplo,

```
library(hash)
```

Utilizando a função hash() para criar a hash:

```
h <- hash(c("carro", "caminhao", "trator"), c("ferrari", "benz", "deere")
```

E para retirar os valores:

```
h[["carro"]]
```